# MySql: can this query be more efficient?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `TIMINGS`

**----------------create----------------**

```
CREATE TABLE TIMINGS(
    SNO TINYINT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TIMINGTYPE VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    STARTTIME TIME NOT NULL,
    ENDTIME TIME NOT NULL
)
```

**------------------ insert ---------------------**

```
INSERT INTO TIMINGS(TIMINGTYPE, STARTTIME, ENDTIME) VALUES
('BREAKFAST','08:34:00','10:00:00'),
('LUNCH','11:30:00','13:30:00'),
('DINNER','19:00:00','20:30:00');
```

so i want to know TIMINGTYPE according to current time and if the next TIMINGTYPE

ex. : if the current time between breakfast start and breakfast end then it should return 'BREAKFAST' and the next TIMINGTYPE

Expected output ex.:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
     CURRENTTIME   |     NEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------
1.  BREAKFAST        |      LUNCH
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

so i made a query which is working according to my requirement:

**---------------------- select ----------------------------**

```
SELECT (
 CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+05:30') ,'%H:%i:%s' ) BETWEEN (select STARTTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'BREAKFAST') AND (select ENDTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'BREAKFAST') THEN 'BREAKFAST'    
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+05:30') ,'%H:%i:%s' ) BETWEEN (select STARTTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'LUNCH') AND (select ENDTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'LUNCH') THEN 'LUNCH'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+05:30') ,'%H:%i:%s' ) BETWEEN (select STARTTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'DINNER') AND (select ENDTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'DINNER') THEN 'DINNER'
    ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE'
 END
) as CURRENTTIME, 
(
 CASE
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+05:30') ,'%H:%i:%s' ) BETWEEN (select ENDTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'BREAKFAST') AND (select STARTTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'LUNCH') THEN 'LUNCH'

    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+05:30') ,'%H:%i:%s' ) BETWEEN (select ENDTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'LUNCH') AND (select STARTTIME from TIMINGS where TIMINGTYPE = 'DINNER') THEN 'DINNER'

    ELSE 'BREAKFAST'
 END) as NEXT
```

---

**So my question is can i make it more efficient? If yes then how!**

**NOTE: I'm using MySql**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Select records which's ENDSTIME is above current time (WHERE), sort by STARTTIME (or ENDTIME) ASC and take first record (LIMIT 1).

Comment: Can you use ENUM type for the TIMINGTYPE? It would increase efficiency slightly, and help prevent errors.

Comment: Hey @LSerni, ENUM types supported by my database but i have to implement some logic to do this because I don't know about ENUM type in mysql before this comment. If you know logic to implement this please give me some idea. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Just change the definition of the field. It will only support a small set of varchar strings - and internally the field will be an integer. As far as the logic goes, absolutely nothing changes.

Comment: I implemented that but i didn't see any changes. The execution time is also same.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
select t.*
from timings t
where 
    (current_time between starttime endtime)    -- on-going
    or (current_time >= endttime)               -- next
order by starttime
limit 1
```

The logic is to search for records that are on-going or future, and then to sort them by date and keep the earliest.

Note that the use of `current_time` greatly simplifies the time logic.

---

**Edit**

After the question was updated: you can use `union all`:

```
-- on-going
(select 'current', timingtype from timings where current_time between starttime and endtime)
union all
-- upcoming
(select 'upcomong', timingtype from timings where current_time > endtime order by starttime limit 1)
```

If you want the results on the same row:

```
select 
    (select timingtype from timings where current_time between starttime and endtime) current,
    (select timingtype from timings where current_time > endtime order by starttime limit 1) upcoming
```

Comment: Please check my question again!

Comment: @Sameer: use `limit 2`.

Comment: Not working as expected. It working fine if current time is available in the table but if current time is not matched then it will return next value and another next value.

Comment: I already done this. Thanks for helping. Is there more efficient way to do this then please tell.